# How to properly use Sessions in ASP.NET MVC Application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, session, authorization

I am implementing a web application using ASP.NET MVC5. I am NOT using the conventional MVC authentication and authorization. I have opted to use `Sessions` instead as my application will be used by very few users and only locally.

I have set a `Session["LoggedUser"]` inside `Application_Start()` in gloab.asax. The value of `Session["LoggedUser"]` is set upon login. I have then checked the value of the `Session["LoggedUser"]` using an `if` condition in multiple actions, such as *Edit* and *Delete*, etc.. If it equals blank string then the user is not authorized on that action/page and vice versa. Such pages will not be accessed directly.

Now, in conventional MVC authorization and authentication, the use of `[AllowAnonymous]`, `[Authorize]` and `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` is very clean. These tags can be placed on any action in the controller and the authorization will be handled underneath. I was trying to find the equivalent of such tags to use in my session-based authentication and authorization. Perhaps, an efficient/better way to use Sessions in MVC application. Kindly guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom filter to do your logic.
[read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs).

add a custom attribute to mark your Actions/Controllers with access restrictions/allowed.
(better to mark allowed instead of restrictions from a security standpoint, future proofing later added Actions)

and in your filter check the attribute of the Action/Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it using Authrization Attribute

```
public class SessionAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Session["LoggedUser"] == null)
            return false;
        else
       {
           var rd = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
           string currentAction = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
           string currentController = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
           string currentArea = rd.Values["area"] as string;
           ...
           //Your business logic returns true or false based on user
        }
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login");
    }
}
```